# Как компилировать быстрее?

Tags: c++

Есть Incredibuild, но она вроде платная?

Comment: Просто интересно - что за проект компилируется, что скорость компиляции оказывается существенным фактором?...

Comment: @Harry, а ведь  вопрос неплохой_ мне тоже это интересно

Comment: @Abyx Плохой подход. Так можно добраться и до "Зачем оптимизировать? Клиент купит себе новый конпутер и всё будет хорошо!"

Comment: @Harry Например любой проект с использованием Qt, с достаточно большим количеством форм

Comment: @Sheridan И примерно порядок времени компиляции? Если, понятно, проект нормально построен, и не требует при изменении одной буквы в одном файле перекомпилировать все исходники? Да и полная перекомпиляция - это сколько времени?

Comment: Всё действительно сильно зависит от проекта. Обычно полная перекомпиляция не требуется, компилируются только измененное (и зависимое)... Ну вот есть у меня проект один - собирается с нуля около семи минут. Но потом, после изменений не больше 10 секунд почти всегда. Ну и вот могу привести статистику небольшую по сборке qt-creator на i7: http://paste.org.ru/?iw8z6h

Comment: Почему минусуется вопрос? Он вполне адекватен и валиден.

Comment: @Harry, игра. Компилируется не долго(примерно минуту как максимум).Но при частой компиляции это долго и утомительно,особенно, когда уже видишь ошибку а компиляция еще идет.

Comment: @RundogieRundogie У вас что, *весь* проект в одном файле? Или единственный заголовочный файл, что нужно постоянно перекомпилировать *весь* проект?

Comment: @Harry, нет, около 50. Код более менее грамотный. Не знаю почему иногда долго компилируется. Не углублялся в подробности компиляции.

Comment: @Harry, скорость компиляции оказывается существенным фактором когда редактируешь заголовочные файлы которые включены во множество файлов.

Comment: Это уже во многом вопрос проектирования. Надо создавать как можно менее связанный код...

Comment: @Sheridan, в участковых хочеться поиграть людям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как минимум можно использовать [предварительно скомпилированные заголовки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) и [distcc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distcc). Ну и вот еще есть [статья от pvs-studio](https://www.viva64.com/ru/b/0549/). И вот еще [про distcc+ccache](https://habr.com/ru/post/111324/)

Comment: Спасибо как будет время почитаю. Вопрос: если я короткие функции пишу в хэдере компиляция может быть дольше из за этого?

Comment: Тут скорее важно не количество функций в хидере, а то как часто он меняется. После изменений в хидере будут перекомпилированы все сорцы, в которые он включен.